# why is my gnuplot result (png from csv) not what I expected?

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

(gnuplot 5.2.5, Centos 7) I've tried about 8 google examples and my result is still not even close.
Here is my data:

> Timestamp,1016.qmgr,1893.sshd,1.systemd,2017.sshd
>   2018-11-21.04:23:03,0.1,1.0,4.0,2.0
>   2018-11-21.04:23:04,0.2,2.0,5.0,4.0
>   2018-11-21.04:23:05,0.3,3.0,6.0,8.0

Here are my plot settings:

```
 set datafile separator ","
 set title "CPU % Usage per task over time"
 set ylabel '% CPU'
 set xlabel 'Time'
 set grid
 set term png
 set output '10.png'
 set key autotitle columnheader
 plot for [i=2:5] 'Results.10/CPU.csv' using 1:i'
```

Basically, I was expecting something like this:
[image]

But I got something like this:
[image]

Any ideas what to set in the plot parameters file?

Comment: Please read the comments of tags before applying them, the "linux" tag was wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell gnuplot that the first column contains time data, and also what the format is:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S"
```

There are other ways to do it, but that is the simplest way to deal with time specified as a string.

[amended answer]
If you just want the content of the first column printed along x as an opaque text string, the command is:

```
plot for [i=2:5] 'Results.10/CPU.csv' using 0:i:xticlabels(1)
```

Because these strings are very long, you probably will need to rotate the labels so they do not overlap:

```
set xtics rotate by -45
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you want.  The example plot you showed has time values along the x axis so I thought that is what you wanted.  If you just want the content of column 1 printed as an opaque text blob, the command is different.  See amended answer

Comment: actually that somehow helped. I am still not sure how, as the series that represents the x values is nicely sorted anyway. I had other problems with that plot properties file but I seem to be on top of it now. Thanks!